# What is causing this strange behaviour in my lwc combobox?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, error, lightning-combobox

I have a lightning-combobox with a onchange function that calls an apex method.

From the onchange, when I select a new value I can see the method getting called and returning values.

But once the onchange function is called, I see a script error:

```
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/na139/auraFW/javascript/dDIdorNC3N22LalQ5i3slQ/aura_prod.js:952:169
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/na139/auraFW/javascript/dDIdorNC3N22LalQ5i3slQ/aura_prod.js:952:362
dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/na139/auraFW/javascript/dDIdorNC3N22LalQ5i3slQ/aura_prod.js:12:29820
p.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/na139/auraFW/javascript/dDIdorNC3N22LalQ5i3slQ/aura_prod.js:12:2436
p.handleSelect()@https://xuz.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/combobox.js:1:5539
```

My combobox markup:

```
    <lightning-combobox
        name="object"
        label="Object To Map"
        value={value}
        options={options}
        onchange={handleChange} >
</lightning-combobox>
```

My JS file:

```
    handleChange(event){
    this.selectedObj = event.target.value;
    console.log(`the objet is ${this.selectedObj}`);
    fetchObjectSchema({
        objectSelected: this.selectedObj
    })
    .then(objectFieldMap => {
        console.log(`the return is ${JSON.stringify(objectFieldMap)}`);
        this.objectFields = objectFieldMap;
        let returnObj = objectFieldMap;
        console.log(`the firstIndex >>>> ${JSON.stringify(returnObj[0])}`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })

    console.log(`objectFields is ${objectFields}`);        
}
```

I can see the execution going into the .then block and also print out the **the firstIndex >>>> ** line.

Even then, the script error is thrown for every onchange call.

Can anyone here let me know what I seem to be mssing?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this:

```
console.log(`objectFields is ${objectFields}`);
```

`objectFields` is a variable, so you will have to do a  `this.objectFields`, also is there a reason you are trying to print **console.log(`objectFields is ${objectFields}`);** outside the promise method.

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thanks @Nagrendra Singh!